# AJAX call and getting return data in Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm wanting to make an ajax call from the client to the backend. I get a successful call from the success function, however, I can't understand how I get data from the server to return from the client.

currently my error trying to use res.send is:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

## AJAX

```
function getProfessorResults() {
      var textData = $('#inputsm').val();

      var data = {user:"gopal@gmail.com"};
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000',
          data: { theme: "somevalue", snippet: { name: "somename", content: "somevalue" } },
          method: 'POST',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          timeout: 5000,
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(data) {
              console.log("success");
          },
          complete: function(data) {
            console.log("completed");
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              alert('Error connecting to the Node.js server... ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
          }
      });
    }
```

## JS Backend

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {


  function passList(profArray, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      callback(profArray);
    }, 1000);
  }


  function getProfs(teacher_name, successCallback) {

    google.resultsPerPage = 10
    var nextCounter = 0

    google(teacher_name, function (err, res){
      if (err) console.error(err)
      var teacher_results = []; //Hold all the teachers returned from the function
      for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
        var link = res.links[i];
        if (!link.title.includes('Add') || !link.title.includes('RATINGS') || !link.title.includes("Hint")) {

            teacher_results.push(link.title);

        }//End if for comparisons ||
      } //End For
      successCallback(teacher_results);
    }); //End google function
      teacher_results = ['tester1', 'tester2'];
      successCallback(teacher_results);
  } //End searchForProfessor


  getProfs(teacher_name, function(data) {
    prof_list = data;
    console.log(prof_list);
    return true;
  });


  if (req.method == 'POST'){
      console.log("true");
      // dataReceived = JSON.parse(req);
      // console.log(dataReceived);
      var obj = {
          tid: 'ryan'
      };

      res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
   }



  res.render('home', {
    profs: prof_list,
    dataStuff : dataReceived
  });
};
```

Comment: `return` to where? Need to know more about server code context

Comment: Say I call a method on the server-side. I want the data from the server to return, say a string of data or JSON obj, back to the client so I can throw it onto my template.

Comment: You need to include more of your JS Backend code.

Comment: @JAM updated the original

Comment: I think error occurred because you call res.render after res.send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the backend, you should have some route where your AJAX call lands. In there, you can invoke `send` on your response.

In node.js/express, this would look something like

```
app.get('/ajaxURL', function (req, res) {
  res.send('I want this string to return to the client');
});
```

To access the data from the frontend, access it in your AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({url: '/ajaxURL'}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: How can i access the data from res.send in the ajax function on the client?

Comment: You have success callback and it has parameter data, so you can get access by reading this parameter

Comment: I created a new route and it's working with returning data, which is what I want. The problem I still have is when I do res.send(req.body), the return data is blank. Is there a reason for this? Shouldn't it print the data I passed into it from the initial AJAX call?

Comment: You potentially need to parse the body of the request before you can access it (e.g. Express has a middleware called bodyparser), or maybe you cannot send an object back to the server (try res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body)) to see if that's the culprit). If this doesn't help, please ask another question.

Answer (score 3):

I am not getting the context properly but you can figure out by this example .

Sending data from server
`response.send("Your data");`
Access this data in your client in success method of AJAX:
`success:function(data){console.log(data)};`